# Is it ok for me to switch from first person to third person here, or can I do this better in first person?

Tags: writing-style, relative-clauses, reflexives, third-person, grammatical-person

I’m currently trying to update my résumé from my tired old version to something more up to date. I’m currently having a little trouble with wording here:

> I’m a self-directed learner who has taught himself (and is still learning) to work with Linux systems.

The switch between first and third person seems natural to me, but I'm told it’s a bit odd. I’m wondering whether it’s correct, and if not, how I’d word it.

Comment: Your sentence is now _sententia non grata_ in the IT world, according to some résumé mavens on ZDNet. In addition, it's quite verbose. Saying "I taught myself enough Linux to be an efficient system administrator for my employer's 50 Linux servers and 100 Linux desktops" is substantial (says more than twice as much) & is only 3 words longer than the vague 18-word verbosity you offer as new bubbly instead of the flat beer you're tired of. Don't use tired old clichés or otherwise dress up in gerontic language if you want to attract positive attention instead of groans & snorts.

Comment: My current work or school has no linux systems. I learnt linux *in spite of* not because of my current situation. While there's room for improvement, the fact that I learn best through experience and on my own is something I want any future employers to realise clearly. I mostly run my own crap

Comment: I understand. I've taught myself most of what I know about IT & set up my own network at home. My point's that self-promoting phrases like "I'm a self-starter/people person/good communicator" etc. mean nothing without a specific context, so your challenge is to say something with more content than "I taught myself Linux & am still learning...". Why? How much do you know? What can you do with it? How often do you use it & what do you use it for? Which distro(s)? What makes you different from others in your position? There's no substitute for OJT, motivation, & autodidacticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence "*I’m a self directed learner who has taught himself (and is still learning) to work with Linux systems.*" The phrase "*a self directed learner*" is the antecedent of the relative pronoun *who*.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with cut-and-paste.